# Django-Storages change s3 bucket on existing object

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage

I have a django app that allows files to be uploaded to an S3 bucket using django-storages. The file is for a part that needs to be approved. Once it is approved, I'd like to move the file to a different S3 bucket.

```
class DesignData(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(storage=PublicMediaStorage())
    ...
```

```
class PublicMediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = "media"
    default_acl = "public-read"
    file_overwrite = False
```

After approval, I copy the file over to the new bucket using:

```
        client.copy_object(
            Bucket=settings.AWS_APPROVED_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
            CopySource=copy_source,
            Key=design_data["s3key"],
        )
```

The file gets moved correctly however I need to update my object. How can I update the object? Trying something like `myObject.file = "newbucket/myfile.txt"` won't work as it is expecting an actual file. I've read I should be able to update the url with `myObject.file.url = "newbucketaddress/myfile.txt"` but I get an error `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.

Is there a way in django-storages with s3 to update an existing file s3 bucket?

Comment: You say that `myObject.file = "newbucket/myfile.txt"` then saving the object won't work, but have you tried it? I remember long time ago I had a similar problem and that solution really worked for me

Comment: @pleasedontbelong I have tried this and there are a few issues. I usually get an error stating that this is not a file so I've tried to get the file from s3, then store it back in as a file and with the new bucket content. This does not work as I will get the old bucket content basically attached to the new bucket info such as myObject.file = "oldbucketinfonewBucket/myfile.txt" I assume this is the storage info running regardless of what I enter on the bucket content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using somewhat of a workaround to resolve my issue. I ended up changing my model to include another file which would then store the new s3 bucket location.

```
class DesignData(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(storage=PublicMediaStorage())
    approved_file = models.FileField(storage=ApprovedPublicMediaStorage())
```

I added ApprovedPublicMediaStorage():

```
class PublicMediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = "media"
    default_acl = "public-read"
    file_overwrite = False
    custom_domain = "newbucketlocation0.s3...."
```

I did learn the hard way so make sure to include the `custom_domain` otherwise it will use the default_storage in the settings if it has been assigned. After I copy the file over to the new storage, I delete the old file and change `file = null` so only `approved_file` contains an s3 object.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to manually build the path to the new bucket. Boto3 docs will guide you.

Get the bucket location, name and object key. You can build the path to the object